# How to use geteric result types in spring @RestController

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, jackson2

Is there are any way to use generic types as a result parameter in spring @RestController?

I have this class:

```
public class Response<T> {
    private final T data;

    private final String error;
    ...
}
```

When I trying to use it as a result type I got an error

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = {GET, POST})
public Response<String> ping() {
```

this is an exception:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:259)
```

This check

`this.objectMapper.canSerialize(clazz, causeRef)`

in `AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter` returns `false` for my class.

How can I fix this problem?

EDIT:
I've fixed it this way:

```
public class Response<T> {

    private T data;

    private String error;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY
    )
    private Class<T> type;

    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ResponseEntity in this way for different response types for a single request.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/test",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> testRequest() { 
         ........
        return new ResponseEntity(resultObject, responseStatus).

    }
```

Comment: It doesn't fixes the problem. In this case i need to pass Response<String> object into ResponseEntity body and result will be the same